# How to permanently remove a path from python import path

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm using python. I installed an erroneous module and now I want to delete and reinstall it. Since it is erroneous, I cannot use `pip uninstall` to remove it. Instead, I have to manually delete the packages. I managed to delete the packages, but problem happened to the import path. When I delete the directory of the package, say `/home/mypath/directory/`, from my PC. Then the import path disappears when I run the commands:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

There is no that directory in the printed results.
However, when I recreate that directory, and run the commands again:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

that directory appears again.
How can I make the system not visit that directory?
I know there is an environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, but I only know how to add path using `PYTHONPATH`, I don't know how to remove path.
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: Try `sys.path.remove(your_path)`

Comment: Are there any `.pth` files in any of those directories that contain the path you are trying to remove?

Comment: @Uzzee: you are missing the point here. The OP wants the directory not to be added in the first place.

Comment: @Uzzee This only removes for one time. I hope to have it removed permanently. I know there is an environment variable PYTHONPATH, but I only know how to add path using PYTHONPATH, I don't know how to remove path.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Yes you are right. I find all the .pth files and find there are paths. I remove all the related records and then those paths are removed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is likely being picked up from a pth file in your user-specific package directory.

For me easy-install.pth contains packages installed by pip. You can look for this file and edit out the offending directory.